# react component style to inheriting components

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am creating a simple component that wraps another component, currently it's Dropdown from semantic-ui, but this question is for the general way to do it.

So My components looks like this:

```
class MyWrapComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Dropdown style={WHAT_HERE} {...this.props} />
        );
    }   
}
```

the dropdown component renders this output: (example...)

```
<div>
   DONT_CARE
   <select class="dropdown">
   ...
   </select>
</div>
```

now I want to create a css rule for the

```
select.dropdown
```

I don't want to create this rule in my global scope, I want this css rule to be only in my component.

I tried passing "style" object but it doesn't reach there, any ideas on that?

thanks

Comment: I presume it's [react-semantic-ui](http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown). Dropdown doesn't seem to have a style prop.

Check the source code of `Dropdown` to see if it allows you to pass in any additional props (e.g. with the spread operator), I imagine it doesn't because your style isn't getting applied.

You probably have to do this in css.

Comment: I think what you're after is [CSS Modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules)

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson yes I browsed the source code, I will need to create my own css, but I simply keep this css contained in the component and not global

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this: [The End of Global CSS](https://medium.com/seek-developers/the-end-of-global-css-90d2a4a06284#.leo392vke)